# Не срабатывает crontab UBUNTU Apache

Tags: ubuntu, apache, cron, crontab

Установил crontab, открыл через ssh crontab -e, добавил на выполнение задачу ежеминутно:

```
* * * * * /var/www/domen.com/bot/cron2.php
```

Так же еще пробовал добавить задачу через sudo nano /etc/crontab:

```
* * * * * root /var/www/domen.com/bot/cron2.php
```

По итогу проверяю по базе, там должна быть авторизация (проверка авторизации) не суть, не работает.... Подскажите, пожалуйста, варианты решения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl http://domen.com/bot/cron2.php
```

или

```
php -f /var/www/domen.com/bot/cron2.php
```

укажи в команде

Comment: * * * * * php -f /var/www/domen.com/bot/cron2.php добавить в crontab -e?

Comment: да, если скрипт написан для запуска самостояельно

Comment: А как понять написан ли скрипт для запуска самостоятельно? Дело в том, что раньше я использовал всегда IspManager и там всегда добавлял команду в cron:
wget -O /dev/null https://name.name/bot/cron2.php
и все работало, но сейчас решил сделать самостоятельно без всяких ispmanager

Comment: wget это аналог curl, можно и его. а так выложи скрипт - посмотрим что там понаписанно